# Retrieving date from mySQL in a datetime or timestamp format

Tags: mysql, node.js, date

I am trying to retrieve dates from a date column in mySQL database. My code (mysqljs) :

**today = document.getElementBYId("myDate").value**

The result :

today = Thu Dec 23 2021 14:05:00 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time)

How can I get it to return just the date and time (yyy:mm:dd hh:mm:ss)?

(In mySql - the column type of the field date is set to DATETIME.)

Comment: *The result* This result form is built by node.js. *How can I get it to return just the date and time (yyy:mm:dd hh:mm:ss)?* Use DATE_FORMAT() in the SQL query and retrieve not DATETIME but STRING output.

Comment: As @Akina suggested you can format the DATETIME column using mySql in your SELECT: `DATE_FORMAT(<datetime-column-name>, '%Y:%m:%d %H:%i:%s') AS formatted_date`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have fund a way to solve this problem.

First I capture the date into a variable :

```
`var today = document.getElementById("mydate").value;`
```

(Today is in the format :
Thu Dec 23 2021 14:05:00 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time)

Then I split it (to remove those info that I do not want):

```
var t = today.split(" ");
var d = t[0]+" "+t[1]+" "+t[2]+","+t[3]
```

Next I create a function to format the date :

```
function formateDate(date){
    var e = new Date(date),
    month = '' + (e.getMonth() + 1),
    day = '' + e.getDate(),
    year = e.getFullYear();

    if (month.length <2)
        month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length <2)
        day = '0' + day;

    return [year, month, day].join('-');
      }
```

Then I pass today into the function :

```
`today_x = formatDate(d)`
```

Finally I display it to the form That I am rendering :

```
document.getElementById("mydate").value = today_x;
```

I hope this is helpful. I don't think this is the most efficient way but I have been struggling  with this for almost a week and this is the only solution I can come up with. I hope someone can offer another solution that is less tedious.